# Strange for-loop behavior in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have next problem: arr has only two elements. Next loop tries to execute his body 3 times:

```
var selectHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    selectHTML += '<option value="' + arr[i].id + '">' + arr[i].name + '</option>';
}
```

Next loop tries to execute his body only 2 times as I expect:

```
var selectHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    alert(i);
    selectHTML += '<option value="' + arr[i].id + '">' + arr[i].name + '</option>';
}
```

Why (tested in Firefox 14.0.1)?

Updated: sorry for the semicolon after counter increment, it's a typo. But the code still doesn't work event without it.

Updated: Ok, this code was simplified. Whole code itself:

```
var selectHTML = "";
timeSheet.steps = [ { name:"Leave as is", id:-1}, { name:"Approved", id:2} ];
for (var counter = 0; counter < timeSheet.steps.length; counter++) {
    selectHTML += '<option value="' + timeSheet.steps[counter].id + '">' + timeSheet.steps[counter].name + '</option>';
```

}

In Firebug I can see that timeSheet.steps.length equals 2. By the way, instead of placing "alert(i)" I've added a comment and body executes 2 times. Magic...

Comment: I doubt. The for loops are incorrect (one too many semicolon after i++). The code won't run at all.

Comment: Loose the `;` after `i++` - It may not be the cause of your error, but it's still wrong.

Comment: Show us the code for `arr`. Do you execute both loops in the same place or is `arr` changed somewhere?

Comment: I get a syntax error with this code both in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: My bad for typo. Still doesn't work without semicolon.

Comment: Show us the whole code then. Can you build a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that produces that error?

Comment: @Franza.. I also faced this issue.  for(var i= 0; i< anArray.length; i++){error += "<ul"> + anArray[i]} + "</ul>"; } Replaced it with while loop ultimately. Couldnt identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra semicolon in the loop

```
for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++;) {
```

Try it without:

```
for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
```

This works fine for me (Tested in Firefox 14.0.1):

```
var arr = [{id:1, name: 'test2'}, {id:2, name: 'test2'}];
var selectHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    selectHTML += '<option value="' + arr[i].id + '">' + arr[i].name + '</option>';
}
console.log(selectHTML);
var selectHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    selectHTML += '<option value="' + arr[i].id + '">' + arr[i].name + '</option>';
}
console.log(selectHTML);
```

Returns

```
<option value="1">test2</option><option value="2">test2</option>
<option value="1">test2</option><option value="2">test2</option>
```

Comment: I updated my example and tested it in your browser version. Still works fine for me. Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate what you meant by the body running three times. If your array contains only 2 elements, when `i == 2`, `arr[i]` is `undefined` and hence accessing `id` and `name` will throw an error.

If this is what is happening, then at some point in the looping, the length of the array is being modified with/without an element being added.

Issues that fixed by adding an `alert` are usually timing issues. See this section on [Alerts](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/timing-and-synchronization-in-javascript/)

> Alert boxes (and the related confirm and prompt-boxes) have some
>   strange properties.
>
> They are synchronous in the sense that the script that initiates the
>   dialog is suspended until the dialog is closed. The script waits for
>   the alert()-function to return before it continues.
>
> The tricky part is that some browsers allow events to be dispatched
>   while the dialog is visible and waiting for some user action. This
>   means that while one script is suspended, waiting for the alert
>   function to return, another function might be executed as part of a
>   different event dispatch.
>
> **User interface events like mouseup and click will not fire during the
>   alert, as the alert is modal and captures all user input, but
>   non-user-initiated events like page load, timeout handlers, and
>   asynchronous XMLHttpRequest return handlers, might fire.**

You have not shown code that modifies the `arr` variable. Chances are you have a ajax call some where that is modifying the `arr`. In the first code sample there is no alert, so maybe the entire for loop gets over before the ajax success handler fires. In the second sample, the alert prevents the for loop from executing till you discard the alert. In the time it took for you to discard it, the ajax success handler must have fired.

**Please share all relevant code that modifies the `arr` variable.**

Comment: "body running three times" means that in the Firebug I can see that body runs 3 times instead of one. "when i == 2, arr[i] is undefined and hence accessing id and name will throw an error. " - Yes, there is an error. So I'm asking why the body of loop executes 3 times instead of 2 and I understand that it is very weird.

Comment: As I explained, timing issues are a li'l difficult to debug. Is the `timesheet.steps` modified by any other function? Like a settimeout/setinterval or an ajax success?

Comment: No, they aren't. By the way, instead of placing "alert(i)" I've added a comment and body executes 2 times. Magic...

Comment: a comment? like `//this is a comment` comment? ... I can't think of any more reasons why your first code sample wouldn't work or why the second works with a comment :(